# 12 images in a row, responsive, bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On this page I have 12 images, so far okay. But I like to make them more responsive.

https://www.outdoorequipped.com/

The code I use is follow and I know I am missing something, but I am not sure what.

Also, how I can do, that this div, where all those 12 images are, has a "auto hight?

```
    <div class="row" style="height: 60px;">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<div class="featured-brands">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/asics.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/asics-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/puma.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/puma-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/speedo.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/speedo-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<div class="featured-brands">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/fjallraven.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/fjallraven-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/marmot-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/woolrich.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/woolrich-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<div class="featured-brands">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/giorgo-brutini.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/giorgobrutini-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/kenneth-cole.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/kennethcole-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/dr-martens.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/drmartens-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<div class="featured-brands">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/caterpillar.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/caterpillar-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/sanita.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/sanita-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/wrangler.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/wrangler-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you try 12 col-sm-1 which contains images inside a col-sm-12 class?

Comment: How it could be? Do You have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this! This may help. If you need more responsible, you can group the 3 images into one col-sm-4 with col-sm-4 class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>.imagesize {width:80px;} .element-content{text-align: center;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color: lightgrey">
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/asics.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/asics-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/puma.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/puma-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/speedo.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/speedo-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/fjallraven.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/fjallraven-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/marmot-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/woolrich.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/woolrich-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/fjallraven.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/fjallraven-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/marmot-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/woolrich.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/woolrich-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/giorgo-brutini.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/giorgobrutini-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/kenneth-cole.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/kennethcole-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
<div class="element-content brand"><a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/dr-martens.html"> <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/drmartens-logo-60.png" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples: Example 1 starts out on large screens with 6 columns while Example 2 starts with 12 columns. This is mostly achieved with styling though.

**Example 1**: Starts with 6 columns @ large

```css
.bg {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/2350x400/f00/fff') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.brand {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.brand:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.brand img {
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .brand {
    padding: 10px 5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .brand img {
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/asics.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/asics-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/puma.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/puma-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/speedo.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/speedo-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/fjallraven.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/fjallraven-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/marmot-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/woolrich.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/woolrich-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/giorgo-brutini.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/giorgobrutini-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/kenneth-cole.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/kennethcole-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/dr-martens.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/drmartens-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/caterpillar.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/caterpillar-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/sanita.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/sanita-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/wrangler.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/wrangler-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**Example 2**: Starts with 12 columns @ large

```css
.bg {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/2350x400/f00/fff') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.brand {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.brand:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.brand img {
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .brand {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .brand img {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .brand {
    padding: 10px 5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .brand img {
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/asics.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/asics-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/puma.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/puma-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/speedo.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/speedo-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/fjallraven.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/fjallraven-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/marmot-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/woolrich.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/woolrich-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/giorgo-brutini.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/giorgobrutini-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/kenneth-cole.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/kennethcole-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/brands/dr-martens.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/drmartens-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/caterpillar.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/caterpillar-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/sanita.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/sanita-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">
      <div class="element-content brand">
        <a href="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/work/brands/wrangler.html">
          <img class="imagesize" alt="" src="https://www.outdoorequipped.com/media/wysiwyg/four_cats/logos/wrangler-logo-60.png" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```